# minSdkVersion vs targetSdkVersion vs maxSdkVersion

Tags: android, runtime-permissions

Need information on how minSDKversion , maxSDKVersion and TargetSDKversion will impact android application's CompileTime , runtime behavior and also how above above flags impact app's installation.

I'm writing one application targeting  android API level 24 and lower version.
since Runtimepermission feature was introduced in API level 23(Android M).

What I want to achieve is,  If application is running on Device whose API level is more than 23 then application has to make use of Runtime Permission feature, if app is running on device API level 22 or less, than application should not make use new Runtime Permission.

to achieve above behavior what should be the value for minSDKversion, targetSDKversion and maxSDKversion?

apart from the minSDKversion, targetSDKversion and maxSDKversion values, do i need to explicitly check the API level in java code while requesting the permission?

Comment: One of the best post about it: https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/picking-your-compilesdkversion-minsdkversion-targetsdkversion-a098a0341ebd

Answer (score 0):

**1. minSdkVersion** — The minimum version of the Android platform
    on which the application will run, specified by the platform's API
    Level identifier.

**2. targetSdkVersion** — Specifies the API Level
        on which the application is designed to run. In some cases, this
        allows the application to use manifest elements or behaviors defined
        in the target API Level, rather than being restricted to using only
        those defined for the minimum API Level.

**3. maxSdkVersion** — The maximum version of the Android platform
    on which the application is designed to run, specified by the
    platform's API Level identifier. Important: Please read the
    documentation before using this attribute.
**maxSdkVersion which usage not recommended is a partial opposite of minSdkVersion.**

For more details See [official docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html)

Comment: @a_local_nobody link updated. see now.